# Ember model computation, server or client?

Tags: model, ember.js

I have a simple model that's stored on server:

**1. Server model (or fixture)**

```
availableHours:[{from,to},...]
holidays:[{from, to},...]
sales:[{from, to},...]
```

On the client however this turns into a rather complex 2d matrix, showing the time overlaps, different renderings based on user selection, so on the client after I parse and compute it, it would look like this:

**2. Client model**

```
[
[{date:11/09, from:09:00, to:17:00, tags:['sales']},
{date:11/10, from:09:00, to:17:00, tags:[]}
],
//....
]
```

Basically a 2d matrix, a time span (from today to whatever user selects), that I can slap onto a table, a calendar-like UI that renders and updates itself automatically as the model changes. So now when I retrieve the next set of data (#1), I calculate it on the client to produce the client model (#2).

Checking the Ember docs (getting started), It seems as if I'd had to compute the #2 model on the server and send it to client. This seems as on overhead as the original data, as you can see is much smaller, perfect for sending over the internet. The second data is bigger, yet perfect for rendering into a table.

What should I define as my model structure in ember, #1 or #2? And if it's #1, how do I compute and map it to auto change the view as the user makes changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your post is not so clear to me, here is my understanding.

I would prefer the first way as its more cleaner approach.

```
availableHours:[{from,to},...]
holidays:[{from, to},...]
sales:[{from, to},...]
```

how do I compute and map it to auto change the view as the user makes changes.

As you said in your post, computation would happen in the client side to `retrieve` the second set of `data`. You can bind your view to model through the `valueBinding` property which would make the auto changes to your view as your model changes.

You can also use `computed properties` to listen to the changes happening in your model

Comment: I will look into these. What about if I store local data in fixtures. and then recompute and reconstruct the fixtures? Check their example and change something in the fixtures. http://jsbin.com/oKuwomo/1/edit

Comment: I am just thinking on why you want the response to store in local-storage or use the store. Here are two examples from my GitHub, which might help you...

Comment: https://github.com/vinothbabu/emberjs-examples/tree/master/EmberJs%20-%20WebService%20Example

Comment: https://github.com/vinothbabu/emberjs-examples/tree/master/EmberJs%20-%20BookMark

Comment: I'll try to split the question into smaller ones. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793522/ember-not-updating-the-view-on-model-change

Comment: @Ska: i think you got the answer for the question you posted in the above link... good luck... i would suggest you get in discuss.emberjs.com where you can get more support related to emberjs...