# Ember not updating the view on model change

Tags: view, model, ember.js

This fiddle has the starter kit recreated, with and extra button that alters the model.

http://jsfiddle.net/UjacC/1/

However, when clicking change, the array changes, but the view is not being updated. Why?

```
<title>Ember Starter Kit</title>

<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
        <button id="btnChange">change model</button>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          console.log(stuff);

          $("#btnChange").click(function(){
            stuff.push("d");
            console.log("change",stuff);
          });

      });
    </script>

</body>




App = Ember.Application.create();

var stuff = ["a","7","b","c"];

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return stuff;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of stuff.push you need to use Embers [`pushObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject) which will notify listeners of an object that there was a change to it.

#### EDIT:

Here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UjacC/2/

Comment: Sweet. What if we wanted to completely recompute and swap the model, such as this: http://jsfiddle.net/UjacC/3/

Comment: Would that work also with multidimensional arrays? Can you also point me to the docs explaining this? There is no way to set the model as dirty which would force a re-fetch and recompute?

Comment: It really depends on the specific use case and what you're trying to do.  Check out [this](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html) link for extra goodies and remember to check my answer as solved if that worked for you :D

Comment: There is no way to set the model as dirty which would force a re-fetch and recompute? Marked as solved, it's been a pleasure fiddling with you sir.

Comment: I believe that (if you're using Ember Data) any changes to a model would set a dirty property to true on it, but I don't use ED so I'm not 100% sure of that.